# Is something wrong with my photo-isolator circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation

Simulate the circuit of Figure# 7.1 using Proteus, for that you will need to replace the ID LED and IR Photo-Transistor with a Photo-Isolator such as the 4N35.

This is the circuit we got.

[image]

[image]
This is circuit I change it to.

When I run the circuit this. is what I get in the oscilloscope?

[image]

Comment: Why did you use an oscilloscope at the input instead of an oscillator (generator)? The oscilloscope does not generate any signal. We using the oscilloscope to be able to "see" the signal.

Comment: I just followed 7.1 circuit.

Comment: @G36   I don't think that's an oscilloscope in the schematic, it's an "oscillator" i.e. signal generator????

Comment: Ok   I get it. Thanks.